# check if variable is higher than item in array php

Tags: php, arrays, compare

I want to check if a variable is greater than or equal to an item in an array.

I've tried multiple for loops, but then they just stack and stack and stack. I just need to get the dates, for example: 01-01-2005 / 01-01-2006 
and compare those two both with today's date and check if today's date is greater then or equal to the date of the book. And if the book is older then today's date do some code

```
foreach ($user_out as $userOut) {
    $userOut_id[] = $userOut['user_id'];
    }
    $userOut_id_implode = implode(',',$userOut_id);
//loop through each element from the tocomet able
$dateOfBook = [];
$today = date("d-m-Y");
foreach ($out as $outs) {
    $datum = $outs['released'];

    //gets the date of the selected book.
    $bookDate = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($datum));
    $dateOfBook[] = $outs['released'];

    //gets the name of the author
    $author_name = $outs['author'];

    //gets the title of the book
    $book_title = $outs['book_title'];

    $today = strtotime($today);
    $bookDate = strtotime($bookDate);
    //checks if today is equal or smaller then the bookdate 

}
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$y = count($dateOfBook);

for($x = 0; $x < $y; $x++){
    echo $x;
};

if($today >= $dateOfBook($x)){
    do stuff
}
```

Comment: `$dateOfBook` just access the element you want to compare: `$dateOfBook[1]`

Comment: But I want to compare all of them with $today.

Comment: @AngelofDemons Why not use a for or foreach loop?

Comment: Do another cycle. `foreach($dateOfBook as $xpto)`

Comment: @AngelofDemons So you want to check if all array element are smaller than `$today`?

Comment: Yes , it is possible. But your script suggests some additional questions: could be you consider directly retrieve dates < today from database or not? what format has your `$outs['released']`? `d-m-Y`? or it is a mysql datetime?

Comment: mysql datetime. and if I use another foreach it will loop through it multiple times. and I want to store it in my database and it will store it multiple times because it loops through it multiple times

Comment: If you only want books that are released before today, try to use the database to filter that for you. `where released <= CURDATE()` ...

Comment: ^ I support @Raphioly-San petition :)

Comment: @AngelofDemons If none of the answers come close, maybe you should clarify/specify/explain in more words what you really want done in this particular piece of code...

Comment: As I gather you want to 1) select books that are older than today and 2) do something with those... Except, where does `$out` come from (which was asked before, but in another way)

Comment: $out comes from a mysql query selecting all the books from tocome table

Answer (score 0):

```
$dateOfBook = [];
$today = date("d-m-Y");
$flag = 0;
foreach ($out as $outs) {

    //gets the date of the book out of the database 
    if($today >= $outs['released']){
        $flag++;
    }
    $dateOfBook[] = $outs['released']; # is this necessary?
}

if($flag){
   # do something
}
```